# How do I remove complex filters created with the "OR" comparator?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

How do you use removeFilter to get rid of complex filters (like in this example from the documentation)?

http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/filter#func-complex

The example below applies a filter that will let through rows with a age of greater than 52 AND (either a height of less than 142 OR with the name steve)

```js
table.setFilter([
    {field:"age", type:">", value:52}, //filter by age greater than 52
    [
        {field:"height", type:"<", value:142}, //with a height of less than 142
        {field:"name", type:"=", value:"steve"}, //or a name of steve
    ]
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Remove All Filter

If you want to remove all filters you can call the ***clearFilter*** function

```js
table.clearFilter();
```

#### Remove One Complex Filter

At the moment there is no way to remove one filter in a complex filter set directly. The best approach in this case would be to use the ***getFilters*** function to retrieve the current filter list, then splice the filter from the array you want to get rid off, then set the filters again.

For example if you wanted to get rid of the "name" filter from your above example:

```js
var filters = table.getFilters();

filters[1].splice(1,1) //remove second filter from the `OR` section of the complex filter array

table.setFilters(filters);
```

Comment: I was hoping i could just remove the individual filter that i created with the "OR" comparator. For example:   

0: Array(2)

[
        0: {field: "declarationType", type: "=", value: "Earthquake"}
        1: {field: "declarationType", type: "=", value: "Flood"}
]

1: {field: "declarationRequestNumber", type: "like", value: "530"}
2: {field: "disasterNumber", type: ">", value: "3"}
3: {field: "disasterNumber", type: "<=", value: "20"}  

How would i get rid of index [0] in the array of filters while preserving the rest? Or is that not possible?

Comment: There is no built in way to do this at present but i have edited the answer above to show how you could approach it